# ASP.NET Core Razor Pages Keep Display Data on Postback

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I've read many questions/answers related to this, but I still feel like I'm missing something. I've dumb'd everything down a bit to make it easier to read, but essentially my issue is this -

I have a razor page where the user can edit a company model. The user can only edit, let's say 1 field, which is the `company name`. However, I need to display about 20 different informative fields for that company.

On postback, I check if my model is valid and if it isn't, I return `Page()`. The problem is all of my display data gets lost. That means that I have resorted to putting 20 different hidden inputs along with each property because I need it in case of a model error.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
        //*** success - return user to a different page
     }
     return Page();
}

<p>@Model.Company.Location.Name</p>
<form class="row" method="post">
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Company.CompanyId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Company.Location.Name)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Company.Location.City)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Company.Location.State)
    //*** more listed here


    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Company.Name)
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

There's a bit of what my html looks like just so you get the idea. Do I really have to put all the label values in a hidden input to make sure I keep them in case of a model state error?

Just looking for the best practice as this seems very...not correct.

Comment: Simply put, if you leave out a property from the model (not pass it as a form field) when render the form, it will come back as null.

Comment: @LgSon So this is the "best practice" or the way to do it? It just seems like there's a better way to do it. If not, then that's the answer I was looking for.

Comment: One possible solution/workaround would be to only bind the `Name` property. With that you can then use the rest of the model data as you wish.

Comment: Let me say like this: _Why bind a custom object filled with properties if you only need to update one of them ?_

Comment: @LGSon Because let's say that in the OnPost, the model state is invalid. In that case, I return Page() to show the user validation errors. Well, when the page gets returned, all of the detail information that the user needs to see i.e. Company location city, Contact name, etc is lost because it isn't bound. Am I handling invalid model state the wrong way?

Comment: @LGSon The OnGet is when the initial company detail gets loaded in via the database. The user then goes to edit something, ModelState is invalid so I want to return the page with error messages, but if I don't have a bunch of hidden inputs to save the detail information for labels, that data remains null.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196391/discussion-between-james-and-lgson).

Comment: You don't need to use `ModelState.IsValid` again, just check if the field the user changed is empty. You can even do this check in `Html` with `required` that way the users does not proceed if data was cleared.

Comment: Just before you `return Page`, fetch the related data from the database and populate your model again.

Comment: @MikeBrind That's the answer I was looking for. Thank you.